# Is it possible to map the same url structure to multiple cloud run services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have multiple services that all reside under the same subdomain that can only be distinguished by the path in a given URL. However, the path in the URL is NOT the name of the service. Is there a way to create a URL map/mask to route traffic correctly to my services if I were to use cloud run? For example:

`subdomain.example.com/path1` and `subdomain.example.com/path2` might map to services `foo` and `bar` respectively. I understand that I can use a URL map that routes `path1` to `foo` and `path2` to `bar`, but I'd also like to send traffic to specific revisions of each service. URL masks allow you to specify a tag, so I could have specific staging URLs as `<tag>-subdomain.example.com/path1` and `<tag>-subdomain.example.com/path2`, but I don't know how configure a URL mask when only the the `tag` is variable. How would I route traffic for:

`<tag>-subdomain.example.com/path1` => `foo-svc (revision=tag)`

`subdomain.example.com/path1` => `foo-svc`

`<tag>-subdomain.example.com/path2` => `bar-svc (revision=tag)`

`subdomain.example.com/path2` => `bar-svc`

I'm open to deploying a separate cloud run services `foo-<tag>-svc` and `bar-<tag>-svc` alongside `foo-svc` and `bar-svc` if that makes things easier.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to map the same url structure to multiple cloud run
> services?

Using only Google Cloud Run and Custom Domains, no

Combining Google Cloud HTTPS Load Balancers, yes.

If you add a load balancer, Cloud Run becomes a backend.

Using the load balancer allows you to use URL Maps to direct traffic to the backends. This also add many additional features. This link shows how to set everything up.

[Setting up a load balancer with Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless)

Comment: thanks for response. I had looked at these docs but I wasn't sure if I understood its limitations. Based upon the my design goals above, I couldn't see how to use a URL mask, because it looks like I must add <service> to the string, but the service's name is not in my URL

Comment: @mvhatch I need more details to understand your comment. Cloud Run cannot remap URLs, HTTP(S) Load Balancers can. If you have a section from the documentation to the contrary, please reference it.